# Why do I get a Run-Time error '1004' on a MacBook when I copy the code from a PC version of VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, macos-monterey

I am new to VBA and learning; however, I am also running VBA on my MAC instead of PC. That being said, I copy the code down just like I have seen in VBA used by PCs and I get a run-time Error '1004'Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. Can someone please explain to me why that is?

My code is simple: `MonthArray(1) = Range("myMonths").Cells(i,1).value`

Thoughts anyone?

```
Sub Array_OneDimension()
Dim MonthArray(1 To 12) As String
Dim i As Byte

    For i = 1 To 12
        MonthArray(i) = Range("myMonths").Cells(i, 1).Value 'This is where the error is
        
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

I was expecting the code to loop through the range and pull out the value in the locals window.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Are you sure that named range is defined on the Mac version of the sheet?

Comment: *Run-time error 1004* is not enough. Please [edit] your post to provide the full, complete error message. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. When you're asking people who are donating their time to help you, it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for them to do so by providing the information you have for them to use. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for pointing that out. I thought I put the entire error message in the body, but took it out of the title of the post.